# Problem 1.8 from Kirby's list

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, geometric-group-theory

**Context**

I looked through a book called "Problems in Low-Dimensional Topology", where Rob Kirby lists a set of problems. He provides a list of problems, states their conjectures, and describes any progress on the problems. The book was published in 1995, so I don't know if some of the problems that Kirby stated are still open or proven. 
There is one problem that stood out for me.

> **Problem 1.8 (Stallings)**
> Suppose $\beta$ is a word in the generators $\sigma_1 , . . . , \sigma_{n−1}$ and their inverses in the braid group $B_n$. If the length of $\beta$ is minimal over all words representing the same element of $B_n$, call β minimal.

> **Conjecture:** If the last letter of a minimal word $\beta$ is $\sigma_i^\epsilon$, then the word $\beta\sigma_i$ is again minimal $(\epsilon = \pm1)$.

**Question**

My question is about the status of the conjecture. Kirby states that this is still an open problem. Has this conjecture been proven since then? I tried to look for stalling conjectures on the internet, but I couldn't find a webpage that talks about this problem. Is there a different name for this conjecture?

Comment: This conjecture makes little sense. How could a word with $\sigma_i^{-1}$ and $\sigma_i$ next to each other be minimal?

Comment: @SamHopkins Presumably the idea in that case is that canceling $\sigma_i^{-1}$ and $\sigma_i$ gives a minimal word.

Comment: @WillSawin: well, okay, in that case isn't it evident that an initial subword of a minimal word has to be minimal? So I guess the relevant case is when the word ends with $\sigma_i$ and we put another $\sigma_i$ on the end.

Comment: I asked the same thing on stackexhange like an hour ago. I would assume the author meant to say that  when $\epsilon=-1$, they both describe a minimal word that represent the same element of the group that has $\beta$ with out the last element.

Comment: Cross-posting: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4870024/3835, but note also the m.se question also has other aspects not asked here